# Difference between the "Simple Medium Linear Motor" (45303) and the "Medium Linear Motor" (88008) Powered Up motors

Tags: motor, remote-control, powered-up

What is the difference between the ["Simple Medium Linear Motor" (45303)](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/simple-medium-linear-motor-45303) and the ["Medium Linear Motor" (88008)](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/medium-linear-motor-88008) Powered Up motors, other than the size and design? Is the performance similar, and can the different motors do different things in the app or when controlled by the remote controller? Can they be mixed freely?

What combination would you recommend for the following use cases:

- Two motors with one 88009 hub and remote controller to build an RC car (movement forward + steering)
- Rollercoaster chain movement
- Helicopter blade rotation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main difference is that the 88008 Medium Linear Motor includes a rotation encoder with 1° resolution. Otherwise it weighs a bit more (34g vs 43g), is a bit slower (380 rpm vs 255 rpm) but also needs less power (60 mA vs 41 mA when freely running). For more subtle differences see [Philo's excellent motor comparison page](https://www.philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm) (where I got the above from as well).

---

As for the recommended combinations for the above use cases, I'd use a 88008 to steer the car (so that you can use its encoder to return the steering to central) and the 45303 to drive it (as it's faster and stronger).

The other two use cases don't need such precise control, so the 45303 should be adequate, if not outright overkill for both of these.